# WebService return multiple values

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I'm developing a web service - restful -, and I need to return multiple values and an image. Something like this structure - I'm not using XML:

```xml
<User>
    <id></id>
    <name></name>
    <login></login>
    <projects>
        <name></name>
        <anotherField></anotherField>
    </projects>
    <photo></photo> ---> this have to be a image
</User>
```

So, as you can see, I have a field with other field inside. I know these options to accomplish the task:

1. Using JSON, but the ideia to return a string of bytes from my image and make a conversion isn't so good;
2. Return using a FormDataMultiPart, but I have problems with fields inside other fields;
3. Put all my strings inside a JSON, that works well with that case, and put that json and the image, inside a `FormDataMultiPart`, like this:

   ```
   FormDataMultiPart response = new FormDataMultiPart();
   response.field("my_image", image, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
   formulario.field("my_data", data_json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
   ```

So, I'm sorry I forgot to ask, what's the best way? Or, is there another way?

Comment: So, which of them have you tried?

Comment: For (3) to implement what issues did you face?  Why is (3) not appropriate?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to ask... I don't know what is the best choice...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're service is, but it seems like you have some good ideas. I would pass all JSON, where the photo field contains a reference to the photo you need. Then you can use some sort of file transfer protocol to retrieve the photo file if necessary, or possibly an HTTP request to retrieve it from the web.

Comment: But, I need to pass the photo, and I just can use with HTTP, mainly because my image isn't so large.